# Why is Squid proxy always turned on and listening by default, in my Ubuntu VPS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, squid

I have an Ubuntu VPS, version 20.04. I installed a few things (NGINX, Python, fail2ban, virtualenv) but left pretty much everything else as it comes.

If I run `top`, I see the process `squid` takes up some CPU power while the VPS is idle. But I never installed squid! So I digged into it (didn't even knew what squid was).

Apparently, squid opens port 3128 on my VPS:

```
squid     537649           proxy   11u  IPv4 18383089      0t0  TCP *:3128 (LISTEN)
sshd      537864            root    3u  IPv4 18383919      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      537864            root    4u  IPv6 18383921      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
nginx     537973            root   25u  IPv4 16468161      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     537973            root   26u  IPv4 16468162      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     537974        www-data   25u  IPv4 16468161      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     537974        www-data   26u  IPv4 16468162      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     537975        www-data   25u  IPv4 16468161      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     537975        www-data   26u  IPv4 16468162      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     537976        www-data   25u  IPv4 16468161      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     537976        www-data   26u  IPv4 16468162      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     537977        www-data   25u  IPv4 16468161      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     537977        www-data   26u  IPv4 16468162      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
systemd-r 538123 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4 18384190      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
```

And if I `tail -f var/log/squid/access.log` I can see thousands of requests made every minute from what I assume are malicious bots!

This is just a tiny portion, probably just a split second of activity:

```
1650805416.411      1 77.222.96.40 TCP_MEM_HIT/200 7160 GET http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css? - HIER_NONE/- text/css
1650805416.419    112 95.216.40.100 TCP_REFRESH_MODIFIED/301 637 GET http://www.digikala.com/ - HIER_DIRECT/31.7.79.114 text/html
1650805416.424     41 188.242.31.148 TCP_MISS/200 712 GET http://core3.proxyswitcher.com/_6870243785063c658699f31edbb33f8e.php - HIER_DIRECT/78.84.180.215 text/html
1650805416.438      0 51.13.126.149 NONE/400 3794 A error:invalid-request - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1650805416.440     42 195.191.32.41 TCP_MISS/200 608 GET http://core3.proxyswitcher.com/mwf.php - HIER_DIRECT/78.84.180.215 text/html
1650805416.453    631 138.2.60.212 TCP_MISS/503 4731 GET https://8du.shop/ - HIER_DIRECT/188.114.96.7 text/html
1650805416.491     38 138.2.60.212 TCP_MISS/503 4702 GET https://8du.shop/ - HIER_DIRECT/188.114.96.7 text/html
1650805416.518     45 46.63.68.233 TCP_MISS/200 608 GET http://core2.proxyswitcher.com/mwf.php - HIER_DIRECT/78.84.180.215 text/html
1650805416.526 123793 194.34.232.236 TCP_TUNNEL/200 219465 CONNECT www.thehut.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/31.177.17.32 -
1650805416.526     34 138.2.60.212 TCP_MISS/503 4658 GET https://8du.shop/ - HIER_DIRECT/188.114.96.7 text/html
1650805416.556     29 138.2.60.212 TCP_MISS/503 4660 GET https://8du.shop/ - HIER_DIRECT/188.114.96.7 text/html
1650805416.569     45 95.216.40.100 TCP_MISS/200 608 GET http://core2.proxyswitcher.com/mwf.php - HIER_DIRECT/78.84.180.215 text/html
1650805416.580    936 138.2.60.212 TCP_MISS/503 4660 GET https://8du.shop/ - HIER_DIRECT/188.114.96.7 text/html
1650805416.588     32 138.2.60.212 TCP_MISS/503 4702 GET https://8du.shop/ - HIER_DIRECT/188.114.96.7 text/html
1650805416.608      0 46.63.68.233 NONE/400 3793 A error:invalid-request - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1650805416.621     32 138.2.60.212 TCP_MISS/503 4689 GET https://8du.shop/ - HIER_DIRECT/188.114.96.7 text/html
1650805416.627      0 195.191.32.41 NONE/400 3794 A error:invalid-request - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1650805416.631    107 188.242.31.148 TCP_MISS/200 721 POST http://core3.proxyswitcher.com/_6870243785063c658699f31edbb33f8e.php - HIER_DIRECT/78.84.180.215 text/html
1650805416.656     34 138.2.60.212 TCP_MISS/503 4711 GET https://8du.shop/ - HIER_DIRECT/188.114.96.7 text/html
1650805416.672      0 223.233.67.29 NONE/400 3794 A error:invalid-request - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1650805416.673    192 223.238.162.231 TCP_MEM_HIT/200 26084 GET http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css - HIER_NONE/- text/css
1650805416.680      0 77.222.96.40 TCP_MEM_HIT/200 20568 GET http://yastatic.net/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css - HIER_NONE/- text/css
1650805416.693     81 102.191.38.132 TCP_MEM_HIT/200 26084 GET http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css - HIER_NONE/- text/css
1650805416.709      0 95.216.40.100 NONE/400 3794 A error:invalid-request - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1650805416.712    173 51.13.126.149 TCP_TUNNEL/200 7229 CONNECT cdnjs.cloudflare.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/104.17.25.14 -
1650805416.729     72 138.2.60.212 TCP_MISS/503 4822 GET https://8du.shop/ - HIER_DIRECT/188.114.96.7 text/html
1650805416.729     47 85.174.197.1 TCP_MISS/200 608 GET http://core2.proxyswitcher.com/mwf.php - HIER_DIRECT/78.84.180.215 text/html
```

From this I gather squid made an open proxy out of my VPS for everyone to use (no idea if it actually works or if these bots are just trying, but it's bad either way!). So my questions are:

1. Is this Ubuntu's default behavior? To launch squid at startup so that it can open up port 3128?
2. If yes: what the hell were they thinking? What's the purpose of this?
3. If not, which application is responsible for doing this?
4. Can I safely uninstall squid or turn it off? If I turn it off, nothing changes on the websites I'm hosting with Python+NGINX.

Comment: Highly unlikely that you did not install it. Probably squid came as dependency. You can check `/var/log/apt/history.log.x` to be sure

Comment: I would also advise you to configure a firewall that only exposes the services you want to expose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Squid comes with restricted rules, so only localhost or localnet (rfc1918) can use it as a forwarding proxy.

proxy can be use for different purpose, either reach outside (internet)  resources from a protected environment, or present some local service to internet, acting as a cache with filtering capabilities.

the traffic you have is a bad thing you should stop asap. first put some firewall rules so no-one from the internet can use it, or eventually set it up so only local service are served through it proxy function, but no forward to internet, or eventually uninstall it if you don't use it, and purge configuration `apt remove --purge squid`

after stopping this bad configured services ask yourself why is it there with a so bad configuration ?

is a bad dependency(with configuration) ?

did someone else install it ?

are you the only admin on the server ?

was there an old squid installation with not purged bad config, that a dependency install has just re-activated.

In short make a security audit of your system.